# Is a continuous function space compact?

Tags: analysis

Is the continuous function space $C([0,1],X)$ compact, where $X$ is compact?

Answer (score -1):

If a set of continuous functions is equicontinuous and bounded, then yes we have compactness in norm topology. This is Ascoli-Arzela.

Banach-Alaoglu tells us that if it is bounded, then we have weak star compactness given that $X$ is a dual of some functional space. If $X$ is reflexive, then it is compact in weak topology.

I think X being compact is irrelevant.

Comment: why a downvote?